# How to insert custom block below product name on checkout_cart_index.xml?

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, custom-block

I want to insert my custom block in `checkout_cart_index.xml` page below the product name. But I do not know the name of that **referenceContainer**. What I want to achieve is, if any product is added in cart, then there will be a custom block rendered below their product name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found out that the **referenceContainer** for this is `additional.product.info`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

Create checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_text_summary"
                   template="Vendor_Module::checkout/your_phtml.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And call static block in phtml.

And create summary.html in this path view\frontend\web\template\checkout.

```
<!-- Custom Text -->
<tr class="grand totals">
    <td class="myClass" colspan="2">
        <span data-bind="html: customText"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And add your code like this in summary.html

here customText is your bind data, which you have to define in your phtml first.